# MPI_Double_Precision vs MPI_Real8

Tags: fortran, mpi

Is there a practical difference between MPI's `MPI_REAL8` and `MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION`? In other words, is there any modern machine architecture for which these two types aren't guaranteed to occupy the same amount of memory? Can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MPI_REAL8` and `MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION` are not interchangeable.

For one reason, `MPI_REAL8` is an optional named constant and so may not exist in your implementation at all.

Beyond that, `MPI_REAL8`, if it exists, maps to a `REAL*8` "Fortran" object, and `MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION` maps to a `DOUBLE PRECISION` object. These needn't be the same thing: with gfortran consider the compile-time option `-fdefault-real-8` and the following program:

```
 implicit none

 real*8 x
 double precision y

 print*, STORAGE_SIZE(x), STORAGE_SIZE(y)
end
```

More generally, you can use techniques in [answer to this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19726509/3157076) to avoid worrying about which MPI named constant to use for your Fortran objects.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning in Modern Fortran a good way to determine what to use is via MPI_TYPE_CREATE_REAL (and related), as this can be used to match directly onto the compilers kind values.